# Integrate javascript in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

This is the code

```
<head>
    <style>
        #divtoshow {position:absolute;display:none;}
        #onme {width:100%;height:100%;cursor:pointer}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var divName = 'divtoshow'; /*div that is to follow the mouse (must be position:absolute)*/
        var offX = 30;             /*X offset from mouse position*/
        var offY = 50;             /*Y offset from mouse position*/

        function mouseX(evt) {
            if (!evt) 
                evt = window.event; 
            if (evt.pageX)
                return evt.pageX; 
            else if (evt.clientX)
                return evt.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ?  document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft); 
            else return 0;
        }
        function mouseY(evt) {
            if (!evt) 
                evt = window.event; 
            if (evt.pageY) 
                return evt.pageY; 
            else if (evt.clientY)
                return evt.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop); 
            else 
                return 0;
        }
        function follow(evt) {
            var obj = document.getElementById(divName).style;
            obj.left = (parseInt(mouseX(evt))-offX) + 'px';
            obj.top = (parseInt(mouseY(evt))-offY) + 'px'; 
        }

       document.onmousemove = follow;
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="divtoshow">
        <img src="http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-preview/35050.png">
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div id='onme' onMouseover='document.getElementById(divName).style.display="block"'>
        Mouse over this
    </div>
</body>
```

This code is for an object(image in my case) to follow mouse pointer. I have put the javascript in the  tags but I want the html to be applied on the whole website instead of one page or post.
How I can do this?

Comment: You could simply make an external script file as explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp).

Comment: ...But there is a [WordPress Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: @doveyg , I didnt know :)

Comment: @TheOnlyError the problem is not with JS , the problem is that where I should put the html so it can target the whole website.Actually I want the above effect on all pages instead of a div block.

Comment: I don't work with Wordpress so I'm not going to give you false adviace, but as doveyg said. Try asking it on there, they will be able to assist you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
//For adding javascript and css
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','wdm_test_script');
    function wdm_test_script(){ ?>
        <style>
            #divtoshow {position:absolute;display:none;}
            #onme {width:100%;height:100%;cursor:pointer}
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var divName = 'divtoshow'; /*div that is to follow the mouse (must be position:absolute)*/
            var offX = 30;          /*X offset from mouse position*/
            var offY = 50;          /* Y offset from mouse position*/

            function mouseX(evt) {if (!evt) evt = window.event; if (evt.pageX)          return evt.pageX; else if (evt.clientX)return evt.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ?  document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft); else return 0;}
            function mouseY(evt) {if (!evt) evt = window.event; if (evt.pageY) return evt.pageY; else if (evt.clientY)return evt.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop); else return 0;}

            function follow(evt) {
                var obj = document.getElementById(divName).style;
                obj.left = (parseInt(mouseX(evt))-offX) + 'px';
                obj.top = (parseInt(mouseY(evt))-offY) + 'px'; 
        }
           document.onmousemove = follow;
           </script>
    <?php }
//For adding content to all pages
    add_filter('the_content','wdm_demo_content',1,1);
    function wdm_demo_content($content){ 
        ob_start();
    ?>
        <div id="divtoshow"><img src="http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-preview/35050.png"></div>
            <br><br>
            <div id='onme' onMouseover='document.getElementById(divName).style.display="block"'>Mouse over this</div>

    <?php
    $contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $contents.$content;
    }
```

Comment: can u please tell where I am supposed to place the above code ? :)

Comment: In the functions.php file.

Comment: This code is working but I dont know why I can not position the image that is following the pointer

Comment: I have used the above code here http://olocally.com/ but I have a problem , the image the is following the pointer hides behind things i,e like mouse pointer it does not stays on the words rather words come on top of it . like here http://prntscr.com/7laeru
how I can overcome this??